git diff of previously tracked files
Once I added a huge directory containing almost binary files and tracked it using LFS.
Meanwhile I decided to untrack the directory and to track the binary files explicitly.
So some text and config files turned back to be untracked (which was intended).
However, since git is not aware about this situation, a diff will show up using the former pointer files now. Is it possible to use some smarter diff which recognizes and resolves pointer files even if they are not currently tracked?
I found a similar discussion here, but I did not understand all the details. But there was a reference to this example, which looks very similar to what is on my mind.

When a file is tracked by git lfs, 2 objects are created. One is a pointer file and the other is the real content of the file. The pointer file is stored in .git/objects and the real content is stored in .git/lfs/objects.
When a file is not tracked by git lfs, only 1 object is created, the one with the real content saved in .git/objects.
Here is an example in bash. In order to reproduce the same objects every time, I set git environment variables with fake names, emails and dates. I test the following scripts and commands in git-bash on Windows 10.
#!/bin/bash

export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=StackOverflow
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=StackOverflow@stackoverflow.com
export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Thu May 9 16:55:28 2024 +0800"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=StackOverflow
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=StackOverflow@stackoverflow.com
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Thu May 9 16:55:28 2024 +0800"

rm -rf foo
git init foo
cd foo
git lfs track "*.txt"
echo hello > a.txt
git add .gitattributes a.txt
git commit -m "hello in lfs"
> .gitattributes
git commit -a -m"disable lfs on txt"
echo world >> a.txt
git commit -a -m "world without lfs"
git log

unset GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
unset GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
unset GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
unset GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
unset GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
unset GIT_COMMITTER_DATE

It prints the log in the end.
commit 5541d7cb72e38236ed76378a6cc39fd120edb03e (HEAD -> master)
Author: StackOverflow <StackOverflow@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Thu May 9 16:55:28 2024 +0800

    world without lfs

commit 1bb4202c14f8d29d8e49afe8cf8be72cff510940
Author: StackOverflow <StackOverflow@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Thu May 9 16:55:28 2024 +0800

    disable lfs on txt

commit f8587ce7a3f0eb3825c215f5b67bcb4e7f11fc7d
Author: StackOverflow <StackOverflow@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Thu May 9 16:55:28 2024 +0800

    hello in lfs

In f8587ce7a3f0eb3825c215f5b67bcb4e7f11fc7d, a.txt is tracked by git lfs. f8587ce7a3f0eb3825c215f5b67bcb4e7f11fc7d:a.txt is a pointer file.
With git rev-parse f8587ce7a3f0eb3825c215f5b67bcb4e7f11fc7d:a.txt,
we can find the git sha1sum of this pointer file is  fa61e1ef71c9908c0926776a4aa3504b3a27f159. It's stored as .git/objects/fa/61e1ef71c9908c0926776a4aa3504b3a27f159. If we use cat .git/objects/fa/61e1ef71c9908c0926776a4aa3504b3a27f159 to show its content, we will see it's encoded. file .git/objects/fa/61e1ef71c9908c0926776a4aa3504b3a27f159 reports zlib compressed data.
With git show f8587ce7a3f0eb3825c215f5b67bcb4e7f11fc7d:a.txt or git show fa61e1ef71c9908c0926776a4aa3504b3a27f159, it prints the content of the pointer file.
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03
size 6

The real content of f8587ce7a3f0eb3825c215f5b67bcb4e7f11fc7d:a.txt is stored in the object 5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03, which is at .git/lfs/objects/58/91/5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03.
With cat .git/lfs/objects/58/91/5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03, we can see its content.
hello

In 5541d7cb72e38236ed76378a6cc39fd120edb03e or HEAD, a.txt is no longer tracked by git lfs. Similarly, we can find its sha1sum is 94954abda49de8615a048f8d2e64b5de848e27a1 and it's stored at .git/objects/94/954abda49de8615a048f8d2e64b5de848e27a1.
With git show HEAD:a.txt, we can see its content.
hello
world

When we use git diff HEAD~2 HEAD a.txt, it compares the objects fa61e1ef71c9908c0926776a4aa3504b3a27f159 and 94954abda49de8615a048f8d2e64b5de848e27a1. The result is not expected, and meaningless.
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index fa61e1e..94954ab 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,2 @@
-version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
-oid sha256:5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03
-size 6
+hello
+world

The expected output is the diff of the real contents of the 2 versions. So, first we need to get the real contents.
In the git-lfs-diff.sh of the example in the question, this function gets the path that holds the real content.
object() {
    Rev=$1
    File=$2
    Object=""

    Oid=$(git show $Rev:$File 2> /dev/null | grep "sha256" | cut -d ":" -f 2)
    if [ "$Oid" != "" ]; then
        Oid12=$(echo $Oid | cut -b 1-2)
        Oid34=$(echo $Oid | cut -b 3-4)
        Object=.git/lfs/objects/$Oid12/$Oid34/$Oid
        if [ ! -e "$Object" ] ; then
            echo "Missing file $File at revision $Rev"
            exit 2
        fi
    fi

    echo "$Object"
}

However, it assumes the file is tracked by git lfs. If a file is not tracked by git lfs, it fails to find the path because it does not exist.
Modify the script (not fully tested and may have bugs).
object() {
    Rev=$1
    File=$2
    Object=""

    Oid=$(git show $Rev:$File 2> /dev/null | grep "sha256" | cut -d ":" -f 2)
    if [ "$Oid" != "" ]; then
        Oid12=$(echo $Oid | cut -b 1-2)
        Oid34=$(echo $Oid | cut -b 3-4)
        Object=.git/lfs/objects/$Oid12/$Oid34/$Oid
        if [ ! -e "$Object" ] ; then
            echo "Missing file $File at revision $Rev"
            exit 2
        fi
    else
        # If it's not a pointer file, write the content to a temp file
        Object=$(mktemp --suffix=.tobedeleted)
        git show $Rev:$File > $Object
    fi

    echo "$Object"
}

diff -urN "$ObjectA" "$ObjectB"
# Remove the temp files
if [[ "$ObjectA" =~ tobedeleted$ ]];then
    rm -f $ObjectA
fi
if [[ "$ObjectB" =~ tobedeleted$ ]];then
    rm -f $ObjectB
fi

You can name the script git-lfs-diff (no extension), make it executable and put it under any path in $PATH like /usr/bin to create a customized git command git lfs-diff. Run git lfs-diff HEAD~2 HEAD a.txt and we can get the expected output.
--- .git/lfs/objects/58/91/5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03     2024-05-09 17:23:00.945185000 +0800
+++ /tmp/tmp.avSyUswsbX.tobedeleted     2024-05-09 18:02:14.896286200 +0800
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 hello
+world

diff -urN can be replaced by git diff --no-index so that it generates a more familiar diff output.
diff --git a/D:/Users/ElpieKay/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp.XZZSA2BDW0.tobedeleted b/D:/Users/ElpieKay/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp.SLQbWhYzfm.tobedeleted
index ce01362..94954ab 100644
--- a/D:/Users/ElpieKay/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp.XZZSA2BDW0.tobedeleted
+++ b/D:/Users/ElpieKay/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp.SLQbWhYzfm.tobedeleted
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 hello
+world

I'm not sure if lfs objects would be packed like git objects. When git objects are packed, like by git gc, they are no longer directly under .git/objects. They will be stored in pack files under .git/objects/*.pack. If lfs objects could be also packed, a path like .git/lfs/objects/58/91/5891b5b522d5df086d0ff0b110fbd9d21bb4fc7163af34d08286a2e846f6be03 is not reliable any more. We can get the real content from the pointer file with the help of git lfs smudge, and then write it to a temp file too.
git show f8587ce7a3f0eb3825c215f5b67bcb4e7f11fc7d:a.txt | git lfs smudge

hello

Modify the function object() a bit more (not fully tested and may have bugs).
object() {
    Rev=$1
    File=$2
    Object=""

    Oid=$(git show $Rev:$File 2> /dev/null | grep "sha256" | cut -d ":" -f 2)
    # Dump the real content to a temp file
    if [ "$Oid" != "" ]; then
        Object=$(mktemp --suffix=.tobedeleted)
        git show $Rev:$File | git lfs smudge > $Object
    else
        Object=$(mktemp --suffix=.tobedeleted)
        git show $Rev:$File > $Object
    fi

    echo "$Object"
}

There is still an issue in the diff output. The paths of the compared files are temp files instead of a.txt. It's okay to view the diff, but it would raise errors when applying it as a patch. To solve this issue, I think we can create temp commits for each version of a.txt with the help of git low-level commands that manipulate git objects.
Another issue is that the script compares only two tracked versions. If you want to compare a tracked version with a non-tracked version, the function needs extra code. We can always first dump the content into a file and then compare the 2 files. FYI, to reference the version in the index, we can use :0:a.txt. If considering merge, :1, :2, :3 may also be used.
# Compare the version in HEAD~2 with the version in the index
git lfs-diff HEAD~2 :0 a.txt


So it's okay to omit the colon as in :0 a.txt? (Last line of code, I expected :0:a.txt as you have it just previously)

@matt git lfs-diff takes 3 parameters. :0 and a.txt are the 2nd and 3rd. In the script, they will be joined together as :0:a.txt.

Thank you for your detailed example.My primary question was: how does git decide to use an lfs smudge? Seems it depends on the .gitattributes only. And such it depends on file/path patterns. If I run a regular diff, git looks into the current attributes to find, if it is tracked or not, and this decision is taken for the other file to compare to, too.

(pressed enter too early...) I thought about something similar to textconv to convert pointer files in general, regardless. But seems this can not be done automatically, since it depends on the files content, not on its name. Or I have to replace the regular git diff by a more intelligent version.
